# How to create a pop under window behind main window in chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to open a `pop-under window` on click, but I want to open it behind the current `window`.

I google this and found nothing useful about my problem.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: why do you need to open popup behind the current window?

Comment: It's called a "pop under," for which there are many, many SO hits... Side note: **Please** don't do this. There's a reason [ways of doing it stop working over time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832409/pop-under-in-chrome-43): It's inappropriate, and browser vendors try to make it not happen.

Comment: I suppose he want to open behind and bellow - may be there must be some alert text which can be not modal.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant pop under,I was able to do this for other browsers as i.e but in chrome the window opened above the current window.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps a simple path setting is what you need. Use this within a javascript sequence:

```
path = window.document.URL;
window.open(path,"_self");
```